# Why ArrayAdapter doesn't use the TextView passed to it?

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-arrayadapter, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer which uses a ListView defined in the main activity layout:

```
<!-- Navigation drawer (left) -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="#e5e5e5"/>
```

and I populate it like this:

```
navMenuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.NavMenuItems);
navDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

// Set the adapter for the list view
navDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.nav_list_item, navMenuItems));
```

As the `ArrayAdapter` needs a TextView resource ID to be passed to it, I use a separate layout file with only a TextView in it for menu items:

**nav_list_item.xml:**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/nav_menu_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textDirection="anyRtl" >
</TextView>
```

**BUT**, the TextView has no effect whatsoever and the menu items are shown the same no matter what attribute is changed!

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just a try: can you try changing `nav_list_item.xml` by keeping TextView inside some parent layout, for instance, `<LinearLayout><TextView>...</TextView></LinearLayout>`

Comment: @shree202, that didn't work either. Even when I give the id of the linear layout, there's no change...

Comment: I posted my own solution. It seems only a custom adapter works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

I made a custom adapter for navigation list and in its `getView()` (@override) used my `textView`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        Log.d("Log", "Null v");
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.nav_list_item, null);
    }


    String s = values.get(position);

    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nav_menu_text);
    textView.setText(s);

    return v;
}
```

Now the attributes in `textView` take effect.

Answer (score 2):

In Resource, you should give `layout` instead of `id` of text view

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.'yourlayoutname', navMenuItems)
```

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. It's still the same (I edited the question).

Answer (score 0):

You should add a param to ensure that the adapter knows what view to map the contents of the navitem.

As the 3rd param, add the id of the textview's id. Like this:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.nav_list_item, R.id.nav_menu_text, navMenuItems)
```

instead of

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.nav_list_item, navMenuItems)
```

Im not sure about this, but if you don't want to use the textview's id, it might work naming the id field to "text01" which is the id of the android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1's textview.

Comment: It doesn't work. My text is still the same, no matter what I change in the attributes.

Comment: What do u mean by not changing? Do you see a value at all?

Comment: I see the text. But for example when I change the `android:textColor`, it won't change. Changing the values in the `ListView` (like background color) takes effect but changing the values in `TextView` doesn't change anything in the output.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String> (Context context, R.layout.nav_list_item, R.id.nav_menu_text, navMenuItems);
```

Hope this helps you...

Comment: I did this and it's still the same. It doesn't take effect.